# Method for Generalising XPath selectors

Tags: xpath

From a table I am looking at on the web in firefox this is an xpath selector.

```
id('ls-page')/x:div[5]/x:div[1]/x:div[2]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td[2]/x:a
```

So i remove /x:tbody because that was added by firefox. But how is it generalised to get a links in the table that have the same base Xpath. the only obvious difference is that tr increases by 1 for each link in the table.

```
id('ls-page')/x:div[5]/x:div[1]/x:div[2]/x:table/x:tr[2]/x:td[2]/x:a
id('ls-page')/x:div[5]/x:div[1]/x:div[2]/x:table/x:tr[3]/x:td[2]/x:a
```

If there are successive tables of links on the page. and the only difference to me appears that div increases from 1 to 2.

So second table link.

```
id('ls-page')/x:div[5]/x:div[2]/x:div[2]/x:table/x:tr[2]/x:td[2]/x:a

/x:div[5]/x:div[1]
```

becomes

```
/x:div[5]/x:div[2]
```

1) Is there a method or process to use to generalize an XPATH selector?

2) For each table do i have to create two separate generalised functions one to retrieve tables and one to retrieve links from tables?

Note I am referring to this site [live nrl stats](http://live.nrlstats.com/nrl/season2012.html) . I have been reading scrapy documentation and beautifulsoup documentation but am open to any suggestions regarding tooling as I am just learning.

Comment: What is it you want to extract from that page?

Comment: @MattH every link in the table takes you to a game summary page. This page is one of 3 tabs I want to extract data from. So for the Xpath above I want to get the link http://live.nrlstats.com/matches/nrl/match15300.html?page=scorecard and http://live.nrlstats.com/matches/nrl/match15300.html?page=team-stats and http://live.nrlstats.com/matches/nrl/match15300.html?page=player-stats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XPATH` is a query language, I don't know of any automated means of generalizing queries, it's something you have to work out for yourself based on the document structure.

My preferred library is `lxml.etree`. Here's a simple working example of a query that should return you all of the match links.

I've saved the html to the working directory to avoid hitting the website frequently while testing.

```
from lxml import etree
import os
local_file = 'season2012.html'
url = "http://live.nrlstats.com/nrl/season2012.html"

if not os.path.exists(local_file):
  from urllib2 import urlopen
  data = urlopen(url).read()
  with open(local_file,'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
else:
  with open(local_file,'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

doc = etree.HTML(data)
for link in doc.xpath('//table[@class="tablel"]/tr/td[2]/a'):
  print "%s\t%s" % (link.attrib['href'],link.text)
```

Yielding:

```
/matches/nrl/match15300.html    Melbourne v Newcastle
/matches/nrl/match15291.html    Brisbane v St George Illawarra
/matches/nrl/match15313.html    Penrith v Cronulla
/matches/nrl/match15312.html    Parramatta v Manly
/matches/nrl/match15311.html    Sydney Roosters v Warriors
[truncated]
```

I'd suggest working with the ElementTree object, `doc` in this example with the interactive python interpreter, to test your queries and have a look at other `XPATH` questions and answers on SO for working query examples to aid your learning.